Is there any precedent for a state giving full-time and long-term state security to a former autocratic leader of another country who is wanted?

Sheikh Hasina’s exile: Lutyens bungalow, heavy security cover


Now, the 77-year-old leader is living in a secure bungalow in central Delhi somewhere near India Gate and Khan Market, intelligence officials with knowledge of developments said, adding that multiple layers of security sheath the former prime minister of Bangladesh who continues to face a slew of death threats over alleged atrocities committed during her term.

Is there any precedent for a state giving full-time and long-term state security to a former autocratic leader of another country who is wanted for crimes against humanity?
Note: I am trying to make it clearer that answeres understand what Sheikh Hasina's resume looks like. She has three features: an autocrat, a fugitive, and receiving full-time state security. Many autocrats fled the country. But I am looking for an example where all three criteria are fulfilled.

History.SE might be able to answer more exhaustively.

Is there any reason you keep changing the title so drastically? "giving VVIP security to a fleeing autocrat", "giving full-time security to a leader of another country who is wanted for crimes against humanity", and "Giving full-time and long term state security to a deserter" are three completely different questions, and you need to make up your mind and make it clear exactly which one it is that you want to ask.

The last title edit seems to change the meaning of the question and invalidate some answers.

Not only is there ample precedent, the usual outcome of an autocrat getting toppled is that they find a somewhat comfortable place of exile. You can find quite a few cases of autocrats that got captured or killed in the process of getting toppled, but someone who manages to flee the country getting returned later seems to be rare.
This is not necessarily a bad thing: It means there is a decent incentive for autocrats in a shaky position to flee while they can, rather than to use any extreme measure they can to cling to power.
Italian Philosopher has already given some example, some more are Mohammad Reza Pahlavi (Iran) going to exile first to Italy, later to Egypt (overthrown twice), Idris of Lybia going to exile in Egypt, Pervez Musharraf (Pakistan) going to the UK, Nguyen Van Thieu first to the UK, later to the US.

"someone who manages to flee the country getting returned later": Alberto Fujimori, Charles Taylor

@ccprog There's also Pinochet.

I did not include him as he did not flee Chile, but could move freely. His arrest was on a request by a Spanish court.

Actually, as far as I realized, Idi Amin is the only proper example.

Yes, France took in Baby Doc Duvalier, allowing him to flee Haiti.
Not out of any particular liking for the jerk (unlike some other African dictators contemporary France had unsavory associations with).
That had the benefit of allowing him to gracefully exit from oppressing his people.
Ditto Ferdinand Marcos, who fled to the US in 1986.  In neither case did the host government really try to further the ambitions of the exiled dictator (Marcos had been an US ally, but an increasingly embarrassing one), they only granted them sanctuary.
With autocrats, be careful not to corner a rat.  Hasina, also of the murine family, left because she could be reasonably expect to be safe from future risks, rather than having no alternatives but to remain in power.
p.s. No, this isn't addressing security levels as such, merely sanctuary.  However, keep in mind that it is an embarrassment for a state not to be able to protect its territory from foreign assassinations so the second - sanctuary - can trigger the first - need for protection.  Modi's India may be more "attuned" than most to the risks of foreign sourced executions as well ;-)
p.p.s. Sanctuary is considerably less appropriate in extreme cases where crimes against humanity were clearly committed at scale, like say Pol Pot or Eichmann.  Many dictators however have committed atrocities, that's almost the case by definition and this answer applies to the run-of-the-mill lot, like Hasina, who was no Omar al-Bashir.

Other cases of note: Alfredo Stroessner, Idi Amin, Viktor Yanukovych

...Siad Barre, Zine El Abidine Ben Ali

If Nazi leaders count, there’s also the examples of former nazis kidnapped by Israeli security forces.

Actually, as far as I realized, Idi Amin is the only proper example.

@JonathanReez That's Eichmann.  Mind you he was only a chief architect of the Holocaust, not the country's leader.  But a dictator with his background certainly should not receive any sanctuary anywhere, even if it complicates effecting his departure.

The title of the question at the time of posting this answer was:

Is there any precedent for a state giving full-time security to a leader of another country who is wanted for crimes against humanity?

Ismail Haniyeh, subject to ICJ arrest warrant for three Hamas and three Israeli leaders, seems to have enjoyed the full state security during his visit to Iran, for presidential inauguration, during which he was assassinated. It is less clear what levels of security he was granted during his residence in Qatar - being a rich man he likely could afford security arrangements for himself (whether he qualifies as a leader of a country is open to debate.) However, at one point Israel did promise to the Qatari government not to assassinate Hamas leaders in Qatar, so Haniyeh's security was treated as a state matter.

By inspecting the names mentioned in other answers, I realized that Idi Amin is the only proper example.

Idi Amin was an autocrat. Checked!
Idi Amin committed gross human rights violations. Checked!
Idi Amin was given full-time security by the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia. Checked!





Name
HR violations
A fugitive from trial
Full-time state security




Ferdinand Marcos
Yes
Yes. Fled to the USA.
No


Mohammad Reza Pahlavi
Yes
No. Fled to Italy and Egypt.
No


Pervez Musharraf
No
Yes. Fled to the UK and UAE.
No


Nguyen Van Thieu
No
No. Fled to the USA.
No


Idris of Libya
No
No
No




The question no longer specifies "autocrat" because you yourself edited that part out. You're answering the question as it originally stood 18 hours ago, not the question as it stands as of your most recent edit a few minutes ago. Ironically, I was just about to caution you against invalidating the existing answers with your edits, and now here you are posting a self-answer invalidated by your own edits.

You also have yet to explain why the other examples don't meet these criteria.

Yes, as other answers have pointed out. (Even Gandhi and Nehru were often treated as VIP prisoners by the British during our freedom struggle.)
Note that India also has a vested political interest in protecting Ms. Sheikh Hasina - if she is assassinated on indian soil it could turn her supporters against India. Awami League Bangladeshi supporters already staunchly believe the allegations of "crimes against humanity" against her are purely politically motivated and legally not sustainable. Many Bangladeshis also already believe India is deeply involved and interferes in Bangladesh politics. Her assassination on Indian soil would fuel rumours and conspiracy theories of India's role in her death and possibly result in a violent backlash against India (war or jihadi terrorism), and even a complete political breakdown of ties between the two countries.

Only the first sentence of this answer really answers the question. The rest is only commentary on the specific situation that triggered the question. But it's not relevant to answering it.

@Philipp Ofcourse it is relevant - why a state provides security to a foreign dignitary they host, or have provided asylum to, is at the root of why there is an international precedent for such things, which the other answers haven't covered.

Many Bangladeshis also already believe India is deeply involved and interferes in Bangladesh politics. --- Not only belief! They have ample proof.

Awami League Bangladeshi supporters already staunchly believe the allegations of "crimes against humanity" against her are purely politically motivated and legally not sustainable. --- Then India should just release her and then see what happens, especially in the absence of an India-overseen kangaroo court.

@user366312 Sheik Hasina herself would willingly come to Bangladesh to face a fair trial even under an opposition government if the opposition truly comes to power through an election and if the Bangladesh military didn't interfere in domestic politics. The current "opposition" government in Bangladesh has only come to power through a military supported coup. They could legitimise themselves by holding an election but they know that they wouldn't win any elections even today against Ms. Hasina or Awami League and that is why these cowards don't hold an election.

ANI and RepublicTV inspired far-fetched incorrect assumptions! (1) there is no opposition in power right now. The current government is a student-backed interim (revolutionary) government. Military only extended its support on the request of the students. Accordinglg to the military, they will give support three years max until the constitution is rewritten. The current contitution was commissioned with Indian agenda in mind which has to go, and also to block future Hasina-like tyrants to come to power with Indian backing.

(2) BD military has nothing to do with interference. Hasina had 11 to generals controlling the military. Majority of them are still in service. (3) Hasina should wait until the interim government rewrites the constitution and holds an election especially because she enjoyed three consecutive rigged elections with direct Indian backing. No matter what, Indian agenda is not coming back on table any time in future.

user366312 What they need 3 years time is to please their foreign backers (by compromising Bangladesh's interest) so that they can successfully rig the next election and retain power, while the military writes the constitution for them. Sheik Hasina is the only leader that genuinely protected Bangla interests, and if she or her chosen successor doesn't come back to politics again (either as PM or opposition leader) Bangladesh will become a failed state. Only a political naive would assume that Ms. Hasina inviting increasing Chinese investment into Bangladesh was an "indian agenda".

@sfxedit, nothing more to say to conclude my comment except there is a proverb in Bangladesh: "when Indian "Dada" are concerned about Bangladesh, be sure that Bangladesh is on the right track" and this proverb is 74 years old.
